# How to display custom field in product description?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, custom-field

I have a **custom field** such as "**_additional_description**", I need to display it at the **end of the product description**, but **only if the product is simple**.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can take the help of hooks WooCommerce provides. Here is the link to the visual hook guide https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Here is the code that suits your need.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', function() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
        get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_additional_description' );
    }
} );
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this solution doesn't work. The theme used is Storefront.